# Writing java-style If statements in XText results in an error

Tags: xtext

I'm writing a custom **Xtext** editor for my own DSL-Language and now want to add **If-Statements** to my language. 
The Statements look something like this:

```
if (TRUE) {
    (...)
}
```

---

But when I try adding them in, I get an error *"A class may not be a super type of itself"*.

This is my code so far:

```
grammar XtextTest with org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals

generate xtextTest "http://www.my.xtext/Test"

Model:
    statements+=Statement*;

Statement:
    VariableAssignment |
    IfStatement;

IfStatement:
    'if' '(' BooleanExpression ')' '{' Statement '}';

BooleanExpression:
    'TRUE' | 'FALSE';

VariableAssignment:
    name=ID "=" INT ';';
```

How can I implement this? Or am I doing something obviously wrong?

Any help is appreciated ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assignments are a important thing in Xtext. if you just call rules without assigning them it influences the supertype hierarchy that is inferred. => it is better to change the grammar to

```
IfStatement:
   'if' '(' condition=BooleanExpression ')' '{' statement=Statement '}';
```

If you want to introduce a common supertype/subtype relationship don't use assignments

```
Number: Double | Long;
```